# Does Solr's autocommit functionality work for deletions

Tags: solr

I have a section of my `solrconfig.xml` which enables Solr's auto-commit functionality:

```
<autoCommit>
    <maxDocs>20000</maxDocs>
    <maxTime>3600000</maxTime>
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>       
</autoCommit>
```

When carrying out a large set of deletions, however, I have noticed that the auto-commit does not trigger a commit.

Is this to be expected? If so, is there a way to configure auto-commits for deletions also?

Comment: Why is `openSearcher` set to `false`? According to [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig) and [this discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Giving-OpenSearcher-as-false-td4085389.html), setting `openSearcher` to `false` might make committed changes not visible right away. And I believe that the default is `true`. Also, your config states that auto-commit would not happen until after either 20,000 documents or 1 hour. You might want to double-check these settings.

Comment: The default is actually `false`. The other two settings are correct. But after 20000 documents, there is no commit. I will further investigate the `<openSearcher/>` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kai Chan is partially correct. This statement:

`setting openSearcher to false might make committed changes not visible right away.`

should be changed to

`setting openSearcher to false will make auto-committed changes not visible right away.`

`<openSearcher>false</openSearcher>` helps you if you are doing bulk additions. During full import, you will first issue a "delete all" and then start adding documents. You most likely do not want to open a new searcher as soon as an auto-commit happens, since your searchable index may only be partial. You have to issue an explicit commit command yourself after you add all your documents for a new searcher to be opened. You can use `/update?commit=true` for doing this.

This statement:
`But after 20000 documents, there is no commit.`

is not true either. There is a commit, but Solr does not open a new searcher, which means your changes won't be visible in search. As soon as you issue an explicit commit, the changes become visible.